# How to convert Keras model to Darknet model?

Tags: opencv

I am having a project using keras (tensorflow backend) to train data and using opencv dnn (cv2.dnn) to detect object. 
And when I used keras model on code using opencv dnn model , I had an error: 
***cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:3644: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Cannot determine an origin framework of files: model_architecture.json, model_weights.h5 in function 'readNet'***

I am looking for method to process this error and have been known that Keras saves the model weights (.h5), the model architecture (.json) (*https://jovianlin.io/saving-loading-keras-models/*), but darknet uses model weights (.weights) and model architecture (.cfg). 
I thougth I must to convert keras model to darknet model, but i don't know how?
So, can you show me how to fix this problem. 
Thank you!

Comment: Please add some code that shows what you have tried and in case you are getting error then add the stack trace as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need:

1. Convert keras model to the TensorFlow: https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow
2. Use this manual to convert TensorFlow model to OpenCV readable format: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

cv::dnn does not support reading keras models that is the reason why you are getting this error. Try converting the model to some other format such as tensorflow.

I used the link below for conversion and got some error regarding leaky Relu as opencv module does not have support for leakyrelu activations if you have not used it try this, it may work.

link : https://github.com/Tony607/keras-tf-pb